# Stop Adding Home Screens on App Install

Tags: home-screen

I do not want to turn off new icons being added to the Home Screen.

Instead there is a problem where my tablet will keep adding new Home Screens.  It's curious, because there is plenty of space for new icons on the previous page.

The tablet is Galaxy Tab S3 with Android 7.0 and the default launcher.

Comment: Can't check on Nougat because I don't have it but IIRC there is an option in Play Store settings to disable this . This is accessible from settings. Please check

Comment: There is an option for adding icons to the home screen.  Not a setting for creating newer home screens.

Comment: Ahh yes, my bad. Must be Samsung specific thing. All I can suggest (since I dint have that device) is to use an alternate launcher like Nova or any other